# Problem while sending data to Firebase firestore from Vercel's NodeJS back-end

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, backend, vercel

When i use this code in local server(localhost) my data is successfully going in to **Firebase Firestore** but when i deploy it on **Vercel** & make request then my data is not inserted into **Firestore** ,here is code :

```
app.post('/create-checkout', (req, res) => {
  let order = [];
  let userName;
  let userEmail;
  let userPhone;
  let userAddress;
  const { products, id, totalQty } = req.body;

  const userDocRef = doc(db, 'users', id);

  getDoc(userDocRef)
    .then((userDoc) => {
      if (userDoc.exists()) {
        const userData = userDoc.data();
        userName = userData.name;
        userEmail = userData.email;
        userPhone = userData.phone;
      } else {
        console.log('No such document!');
      }

      const lineItems = products.map((product) => ({
        price_data: {
          currency: "inr",
          product_data: {
            name: product.name,
          },
          unit_amount: product.price * 100,
          customer_details: product.id,
        },
        quantity: product.qty,
        customer_details: product.id,
      }));

      const productID = [];
      products.forEach((product) => {
        productID.push(product.ID);
      });

      const metadata = {
        'productID': JSON.stringify(products),
      };
      var currentdate = new Date();
      var datetime = currentdate.getDate() + "/" + (currentdate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + currentdate.getFullYear();

      const data = [];
      const nameOfProducts = [];
      let qtyData;
      products.map((product) => {
        data.push(product.ID);
        nameOfProducts.push(product.name);
        qtyData = product.qty;
      });

      const sessionData = {
        payment_method_types: ["card"],
        line_items: lineItems,
        mode: "payment",
        success_url: 'https://ecom2-c701c.web.app/myorder',
        cancel_url: 'https://ecom2-c701c.web.app/myorder',
        metadata: {
          products: JSON.stringify(data),
          quantity: JSON.stringify(totalQty),
          productName: JSON.stringify(nameOfProducts),
          Date: datetime,
          lineItems: JSON.stringify(lineItems),
          UID: id,
          CustomerName: JSON.stringify(userName),
          CustomerEmail: JSON.stringify(userEmail),
          CustomerPhone: JSON.stringify(userPhone),
        }
      };

      stripe.checkout.sessions.create(sessionData)
        .then((session) => {
          res.json({ id: session.id });
          order.push(session.id);

          const orderIds = [];
          orderIds.push(session.id);

          const cartProductRef = doc(db, 'Orders', id);
          getDoc(cartProductRef)
            .then((existingData) => {
              if (existingData.exists()) {
                return updateDoc(cartProductRef, {
                  Orders: arrayUnion(session),
                }).then(() => {
                  console.log('data has been inserted into Orders collection');
                });
              } else {
                return setDoc(doc(db, 'Orders', id), {
                  Orders: [session],
                }).then(() => {
                  console.log('Data has been created');
                });
              }
            })
            .then(() => {
              // Now we handle the user document update
              const userDocRef = doc(db, 'users', id);
              return getDoc(userDocRef)
                .then((existingData) => {
                  if (existingData.exists()) {
                    return updateDoc(userDocRef, {
                      OrderId: arrayUnion(session.id),
                    }).then(() => {
                      console.log('id updated');
                    });
                  }
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.error('Error updating document: ', error);
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
});
```

**Reactjs code for POST request**

```
   const makePayment = async () => {
        const stripe = await loadStripe(process.env.stripeKey)

        const body = {
            products: cartProducts,id:id,totalQty:totalQty
        }
        const headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
// for deployment & localhost ,there are two different endpoints

        const response=await fetch("https://ecom-backend-weld.vercel.app/create-checkout",
        // const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/create-checkout",
            {
                method: "POST",
                headers: headers,
                body: JSON.stringify(body)
            })

        const session = await response.json()

        const result=stripe.redirectToCheckout({
            sessionId:session.id
        })

        if(result.error){
            console.log(result.error)
        }







    }
```

I am using** Promises** in above code , i tried **Async/await **too but still facing same issue

Comment: Did you perform any troubleshooting by stepping through the code line by line, examining the flow and vars along the way until you find something unexpected? If you did, please include your findings - what line isn't working? Where does the code start to fail? Please update the question.

Comment: code is working on localhost ,i checked but it is not sending data to firestore in a deployed vercel backend ,i used 'async-await' too but result is same.